# How do I populate a vue component inside vue condition base with nested json objects

Tags: json, vue.js, vue-component, parent-child, vuejs3

I have a json file of projects, where a single company can have more than one projects executed and some other companies have just one project executed. I want to be able to show the project(s) when the company logo is click . the projects are hidden by default, until one clicks on the company's icon. I have a vue if binding to show if click and a component to show the project.
How can i adjust my code to do that. My code looks as follows:

```
<div class="container" v-if="seen">
   <header class="section-header">
       <h3>{{ projects }}</h3>
   </header>
   <div class="row" id="display-projects">
      <project-executed
          v-for="project in projects"
          v-icon="project.icon"
          v-icon-color="project.color"
          v-title="project.title"
          v-description="project.description"
      ></project-executed>
   </div>
</div>
```

```
const app = Vue.createApp({
    data() {
        return {
            seen: false,
            projects: "Projects",
            unicef:[        
                {
                  "icon": "ion-ios-analytics-outline",
                  "color": "#ff689b",
                  "title": "UNICEF Nigeria – Drivers of Violence Against Children",
                  "description": "VKM in 2017/ 2018 provided consulting services to UNICEF Child Protection section. We conducted the Drivers of Violence Against Children study which required a systematic review of the literature, secondary data analysis and an interventions’ mapping across four focal states (Lagos, Cross River, Gombe and Plateau) of the country."
                },
                {
                  "icon": "ion-ios-bookmarks-outline",
                  "color": "#e9bf06",
                  "title": "UNICEF Nigeria – Time to teach: Determinants of Teacher Absenteeism in Sub-Saharan Africa",
                  "description": "VKM was identified by UNICEF in 2018 to lead the Nigeria component of a multi-country study on the determinants of teacher absenteeism in sub-Saharan Africa. VKM has so far participated in a multi-country training in Ghana and preparing for the data collection exercise which will include key informant interviews, focus group discussions, survey of primary school teachers identified and an assessment of primary schools studied."
                },
                {
                  "icon": "ion-ios-paper-outline",
                  "color": "#3fcdc7",
                  "title": "UNICEF Nigeria – Iron-Folic Acid Supply Chain Assessment in Northern Nigeria",
              "description": "VKM was contracted by UNICEF in January 2019 to conduct an assessment of the Iron-Folic Acid supply chain system in six states (Jigawa, Katsina, Kebbi, Sokoto, Yobe, Zamfara) in Northern Nigeria."
                }   
           ],
           drpc:
             {
               "icon": "ion-ios-speedometer-outline",
               "color": "#41cf2e",
               "title": "Policy and Strategic Plan Development and Research",
               "description": "VKM has expertise in the development of national level policies and strategic plans. Our chief executive led the development of the Nigeria Health Information System Strategic Plan (2014-2018) and the Sierra Leone Health Information System Strategic Plan (2017-2021)."
            },
            fhi: 
              {
                "icon": "ion-ios-world-outline",
                "color": "#d6ff22",
                "title": "Research on Civil Registration and Vital Statistics (CRVS) System",
                "description": "VKM has carried out several studies on birth registration in Nigeria collaborating with researchers across the world in the process."
            },
            jsi:
              {
                "icon": "ion-ios-clock-outline",
                "color": "#4680ff",
                "title": "Health Information Systems Strengthening",
                "description": "VKM developed the Nigeria Health Facility Registry (HFR) for the Federal Ministry of Health. The project was funded by USAID through the MEASURE Evaluation project under an institutional contract with VKM."
            },
            projects: null
        }
    },
            methods: {
                showUnicefProjects() {
                    this.seen = true;
                    this.projects = this.unicef;
                },
                showFHIProjects() {
                    this.seen = true;
                    this.projects = this.fhi;
                },
                showJSIProjects() {
                    this.seen = true;
                    this.projects = this.jsi;
                },
                showDRPCProjects() {
                    this.seen = true;
                    this.projects = this.drpc;
                },
            }
        });

        app.component('project-executed', {
            props: ['icon', 'icon-color', 'title', 'description'],
            template: `
                <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-5"
                    data-wow-delay="0.1s" data-wow-duration="1.4s">
                    <div class="box">
                        <div class="icon">
                            <i class="{{icon}}" style="color: {{icon-color}}"></i>
                        </div>
                        <h4 class="title">
                            <a href="">{{title}}</a>
                        </h4>
                        <p class="description">
                            {{description}}
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            `
        });

        app.mount('#display-projects');
```

Comment: Add an `@click` on the logo which triggers the appropriate method

Comment: Thanks a lot @Daniel_Knights I figured that problem was because I added the binding attributes wrongly. I was using v-item instead of :item.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that in using the component here, I was wrongly trying to bind the props. so this was not displaying the items because, the bindings are not done correctly.

```
<div class="container" v-if="seen">
   <header class="section-header">
       <h3>{{ projects }}</h3>
   </header>
   <div class="row" id="display-projects">
      <project-executed
          v-for="project in projects"
          :icon="project.icon"
          :icon-color="project.color"
          :title="project.title"
          :description="project.description"
      ></project-executed>
   </div>
</div>
```